# No narrowing warnings when using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`

Tags: c++, c++11

My colleague ran into an unexpected issue with `emplace_back` and I am trying to wrap my head around it. The following `test.cpp` is a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
class A {
 public:
  explicit A(int /*unused*/) {}
};
int main() {
  double foo = 4.5;
  std::vector<A> a_vec{};
  a_vec.emplace_back(foo); // No warning with Wconversion
  A a(foo); // Gives compiler warning with Wconversion as expected
}
```

Compiling with g++ 8.3.0 yields the following warning:

```
$ g++ -Wconversion test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:10: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
   A a(bar); // Gives compiler warning with Wconversion as expected
```

So the implicit conversion is caught when a simple object is constructed, but not when `emplace_back` is called.

**Why is there no warning for `emplace_back`?**

Comment: FWIW, `A a(foo, bar);` wont give you an error either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the warning you need to compile with:

```
$ g++ -Wsystem-headers -Wconversion test.cpp -o test
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/vector:60,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h: In function ‘constexpr int std::__lg(int)’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:1001:44: warning: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   { return sizeof(int) * __CHAR_BIT__  - 1 - __builtin_clz(__n); }
                                            ^
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h: In function ‘constexpr unsigned int std::__lg(unsigned int)’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:1005:44: warning: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘unsigned int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   { return sizeof(int) * __CHAR_BIT__  - 1 - __builtin_clz(__n); }
                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/vector:61,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = A; _Args = {double&}; _Tp = A]’:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::construct(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = A; _Args = {double&}; _Tp = A; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<A>]’
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/vector.tcc:103:30:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {double&}; _Tp = A; _Alloc = std::allocator<A>]’
test.cpp:9:25:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

The warning is no longer as clear, since it happens in a system header. Note that it is not enough to only use the `-Wsystem-headers` flag, one needs both `-Wsystem-headers` and `-Wconversion` to catch this.

In the case of `push_back` it is enough to use `-Wnarrowing` to get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of how the default allocator constructs an `A`.  When you do `A a{foo, bar}` you are using list initialization and a narrowing conversion is required to issue a diagnostic.  With the default allocator, it uses

```
::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

where `p` is a pointer to the element of the vector data and `T` is the `value_type` of the vector.  Here they use parentheses instead of braces and with parentheses narrowing conversions are allowed so you don't see a diagnostic message.

If you wrote your own allocator that did

```
::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
```

Then you would get the warning.

Comment: Ok, with `-Wconversion` I get a warning on A a(foo, bar) but not in the emplace_back line, is that expected? Should `-Wconversion` not also catch the one in emplace_back?

Comment: @Gumeo Yes, using `-Wconversion` should also trigger the warning.  Not sure why it isn't flowing through to the allocator.